# Use private rsa key in docker image without exposing it

Tags: linux, docker, ssh, continuous-integration

I have to provide docker image that will be used in CI, and it should has git ssh authorization built-in.
To achieve this I would need to put a private key of git service user inside, but I am out of ideas how to do it without exposing key content itself.

I understand that if end-user is able to authorize with this key from within the container it is basically the same as giving him the key itself, but I am alright that user can perform any ssh auth required operations from withing the image, but do not want key to be extracted and used somewhere else.

So far I thought about copying encrypted key and providing the password to key manager during the build with ssh-add, but of course it won't work because it will save password only for current shell session. Are there any best practices to do such a thing?

Comment: Anyone who has a Docker image can fairly easily get any file out of it.  I'd suggest setting up the CI system proper to run source control operations, rather than risking leaking credentials through a Docker image.

Comment: well, we do that in Jenkins with build in credential storage - and that works well. But unfortunately we also have gitlab ci, that does not support anything of that kind

Comment: Gitlab CI supports secrets - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#masked-variable-requirements

Comment: it is indeed, my problem is that it is revealed to any maintainer of the project it is used in. In Jenkins you can define access to secrets manager to specific people, but secrets can be used freely across projects. In gitlab ci secrets are revealed to whoever has maintainer status in projects they used in.

Comment: ok, nvm previous answer, I have just found that gitlab CI supports group and instance level variables, which more or less covers our case

Answer (score 0):

You can use a containerized SSH server like this [docker image](https://github.com/jeroenpeeters/docker-ssh)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).